# Blocks of different sizes in ScaLAPACK?

Tags: c++, mpi, distributed-computing, intel-mkl, scalapack

I am performing a Cholesky factorization with Intel-MKL, which uses ScaLAPACK. I distributed the matrix, based on this [example](https://andyspiros.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/an-example-of-blacs-with-c/), where the matrix is distributed in blocks, which are of equal size (i.e. Nb x Mb). I tried to make it so that every block has it's own size, depending on which process it belongs, so that I can experiment more and maybe get better performance.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325513/scatter-matrix-blocks-of-different-sizes-using-mpi), in order to get a better understanding of what I am saying. I won't post my code, since it's too big (yes the minor example is too big too, I checked) and the distribution seems to work well. However, *ScaLAPACK seems to assume that the matrix is distributed in blocks of equal size?*

For example, I am using this:

```
int nrows = numroc_(&N, &Nb, &myrow, &iZERO, &procrows);
int ncols = numroc_(&M, &Mb, &mycol, &iZERO, &proccols);
```

where (taken from the [manual](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/allineaDDT/programs/trisol/numroc.f)):

> NB        (global input) INTEGER
>              Block size, size of the blocks the distributed matrix is
>              split into.

So, ***does ScaLAPACK allow distributed matrices with non-equal block sizes?***

---

If I print information like this, for an 8x8 matrix:

```
std::cout << Nb << " " << Mb << " " << nrows << " " << ncols << " " << myid << std::endl;
```

I am getting this:

```
3 3 5 5 0
1 1 4 4 1
1 1 4 4 2
1 1 4 4 3
```

and with by just swapping the first two block sizes, this:

```
1 1 4 4 0
3 3 5 3 1
1 1 4 4 2
1 1 4 4 3
```

which doesn't make sense for an 8x8 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/562742), the answer is no, you can not have blocks of different sizes.