# 3D array scattering using MPI Alltoallw to handle different subarrays dimensions

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, mpi, scatter

I'm newby in MPI and I'm trying to scatter a 3D array across all processors.

Since in my application is likely to not have the dimensions that match with the number of cores I've defined a proper `MPI_Datatype` to handle this and I've tried to setup an example with a `8*4*8` array scattered across `9` processors.

Now it is impossible to use `MPI_Scatterv` and I know that there is no `MPI_Scatterw` function, but I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325513/scatter-matrix-blocks-of-different-sizes-using-mpi/29476914#29476914) and [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.1/man3/MPI_Alltoallw.3.php) that it's possibile to set properly `MPI_Alltoallw` to simulate it, in particular they say, if I've understood well, that I should set the `sendcounts=0` on all the processors, except the one which own the array to scatter.

So I've tried but without success. 
Actually I'm stuck with an error that says `MPI_ERR_COUNT: invalid count argument`

Sounds like the error is in sendcounts, that I've defined in this way:

```
int *sendcounts = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      sendcounts[i] = 0;
  }
  sendcounts[0] = 1;
```

While the full code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>


void printarr(double *data, int nx, int ny, int nz, int rank, int, char *str);
double *allocarray(int nx, int ny, int nz);

#define MODES 4
int main(int narg, char **args) {

// setup MPI
  MPI_Init(&narg,&args);
  MPI_Comm world = MPI_COMM_WORLD; // @suppress("Symbol is not resolved") // @suppress("Type cannot be resolved")
  int rank,size;
  MPI_Comm_size(world,&size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(world,&rank);

  // Antialias along x
  int modes, nfast,nmid,nslow, nx,ny,nz;
  modes = MODES;
  nx = modes/2; ny = modes; nz = modes+1;
  int nxd_AA = (nx*3)/2 +1;
  // fftFitting
  int nxd = 4; int nzd = 4;
  while ( nxd < nxd_AA ) {
      nxd = nxd*2;
  }
  while ( nzd < nz ) {
      nzd = nzd*2;
  }
  // TOTAL Modes
  nfast = nxd;
  nmid = ny;
  nslow = nzd;

  // Algorithm to factor Nprocs into roughly cube roots
  int npfast,npmid,npslow;
  npfast= 1;
  int npmidslow = size / npfast;
  npmid = (int) sqrt(npmidslow);
  while (npmid < npmidslow) {
    if (npmidslow % npmid == 0) break;
    npmid++;
  }
  npslow = size / npfast / npmid;


  if (rank == 0) {
      printf("\n========================================================================================\n"
              "\t2D FFT with %dx%dx%d total modes (%d,%d,%d) on %d procs, %dx%dx%d grid\t\n"
            "========================================================================================\n\n",
              nfast,nmid,nslow,nx,ny,nz,size,npfast,npmid,npslow);
    }

  if ((ny/npmid) < 1) {
      perror("\n\n\nInvalid Y Grid decomposition\nAborting simulation...\n\n\n");
      abort();
  }
  if ((nz/npslow) < 1) {
      perror("\n\n\nInvalid Z Grid decomposition\nAborting simulation...\n\n\n");
      abort();
   }

  /******************************************** Remap Variables *******************************************/
  // partitioning in x-pencil
  int ipfast = rank % npfast;
  int ipmid = (rank/npfast) % npmid;
  int ipslow = rank / (npfast*npmid);
  int in_ilo, in_ihi, in_jlo, in_jhi, in_klo, in_khi;

  in_ilo = (int) 1.0*ipfast*nfast/npfast;                       // I fast
  in_ihi = (int) 1.0*(ipfast+1)*nfast/npfast - 1;
  in_jlo = (int) 1.0*ipmid*nmid/npmid;                          // J med
  in_jhi = (int) 1.0*(ipmid+1)*nmid/npmid - 1;
  in_klo = (int) 1.0*ipslow*nslow/npslow;                       // K slow
  in_khi = (int) 1.0*(ipslow+1)*nslow/npslow - 1;

  printf("[X-PENCIL] (i,j,k order)\t"
          "On rank %d the coordinates are: "
          "(%d,%d,%d) -> (%d,%d,%d)\n", rank, in_ilo, in_jlo, in_klo, in_ihi, in_jhi, in_khi );


  double *arr = allocarray(4*2,4,8);
  if (rank == 0) {
      for(int k=0; k<8; k++) {
          for (int j=0; j<4;j++) {
              for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                  arr[i+j*8+k*8*4] = i+j*8+k*8*4;
              }
          }
      }
      printarr(arr, 8, 4, 8, rank, 0, "Starting array");
  }

  int *contiguous_y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  int *contiguous_z = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  int *sendcounts = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  int *senddispls = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  int *recvdispls = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  int *localdims = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  MPI_Datatype recvtype[size];
  contiguous_y[rank] = (in_jhi-in_jlo+1);
  contiguous_z[rank] = (in_khi-in_klo+1);
  senddispls[rank] = 2*nxd*in_jlo + 2*nxd*ny*in_klo;
  localdims[rank] = 2*nxd*(in_jhi-in_jlo+1)*(in_khi-in_klo+1);
  double *arr_recv = (double*)malloc(2*nxd*(in_jhi-in_jlo+1)*(in_khi-in_klo+1)*sizeof(double));
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      sendcounts[i] = 0;
      recvdispls[i] = 0;
      recvtype[i] = MPI_DOUBLE;
  }
  sendcounts[0] = 1;
  MPI_Allgather(&contiguous_y[rank],1,MPI_INT,contiguous_y,1,MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Allgather(&contiguous_z[rank],1,MPI_INT,contiguous_z,1,MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Allgather(&senddispls[rank],1,MPI_INT,senddispls,1,MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Allgather(&localdims[rank],1,MPI_INT,localdims,1,MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  MPI_Datatype vector[size], contiguous[size];
  int bytes_stride = sizeof(double)*2*nxd*ny;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      MPI_Type_contiguous(2*nxd*contiguous_y[i], MPI_DOUBLE, &contiguous[i]);
      MPI_Type_create_hvector(contiguous_z[i], 1, bytes_stride, contiguous[i], &vector[i]);
      MPI_Type_commit(&vector[i]);
  }

  MPI_Alltoallw(&arr, sendcounts, senddispls, vector, &arr_recv, localdims, recvdispls, recvtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Type_free(vector);

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}

void printarr(double *data, int nx, int ny, int nz, int rank, int desidered_rank, char *str) {
if(rank == desidered_rank){
printf("-- %s --\n", str);
for(int k=0; k<nz; k++) {
    printf("\n\n-----%d------\n",k);
    for (int j=0; j<ny;j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<nx; i++) {
            printf("%.1f\t", data[i+j*nx+k*nx*ny]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
}
}

double *allocarray(int nx, int ny, int nz) {
double* arr = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*nz*nx*ny);
return arr;
}
```

The rows until `printf("[X-PENCIL] ...` are used to determine the dimensions of each block and are necessary in my application.

Any advice will be welcome :-)

Comment: You'd rather use `MPI_Type_create_subarray()` to build your datatypes. I also suggest you use point-to-point communications to scatter the subarrays (`MPI_Alltoallw()` is convoluted and unlikely to perform faster IMHO). If you want to stick to `MPI_Alltoallw()`, then `sendcounts` should all be `1` on the root rank and `0` everywhere else, and `recvcounts[root]` should be `1` on all ranks and all other `recvcounts` should be `0`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot parse your comment. Please append the full updated code to the question. Keep in mind all `sendcounts` are `0` except on the root rank if you are doing a scatter.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thanks again Gilles, I've fixed. My fault were "conceptual", I hadn't figured out that all the vectors were independent from processor to processor.